# How to we use the SoapClient in Cakephp...?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, cakephp-3.0

I have enabled SOAP in my local server.
My code is:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0'); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0'); 
$client = new SoapClient('web_url');
$session = $client->login('username', 'pwd');
$result = $client->call($session, 'function_name', '<id>');
print_r($result);
```

Here it's executed successfully when I run the code on separate php file. But I got this error:

> Error: Class 'App\Controller\SoapClient' not found

when I try to run the code form CakePHP action.

Please suggest me how to we use the SoapClient in CakePHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're in a different namespace, and `SoapClient` is in the root namespace, so use `\SoapClient`:

```
$client = new \SoapClient('web_url');
```

Alternatively,  near the namespace declaration make a `use` statement:

```
namespace App\Controller
use SoapClient;
```

Note: this isn't a CakePHP specific problem, it's a general namespace issue.

Comment: Thanks @Mrcode its working well. 
`$client = new \SoapClient('web_url');`
Perfect answer. Thanks

Comment: Don´t forget to uncomment the following line in php.ini: extension=php_soap.dll