# How do I include a composer library inside a Magento 2 Observer

Tags: magento2

I'm having a problem with my observer namespace, which I cannot figure out.

I want to include a library downloading with composer.

Normally, adding `require('vendor\mandrill\mandrill\src\mandrill.php');` would work.

It's trying to find the class inside the observers php file and I get this error:

> Class 'vendor\mandrill\mandrill\src\mandrill' not found in C:\wamp64\www\html\newmagento2\app\code\Avery\Sandbox\Observer\sendOrderInvoice.php

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I needed to add a backslash when calling the Class.

[How to we use the SoapClient in Cakephp...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460247/how-to-we-use-the-soapclient-in-cakephp)